# Python "Str to Int" within a list of lists?

Tags: python

I want to convert an element "str" to "int" within a list of list.

```
list = [['2003', '12', '5'], ['2004', '10', '7']]
```

to

```
[['2003', '12', 5], ['2004', '10', 7]]
```

Comment: You should use the `int` function.

Comment: you rock mate.. simplest and effective answer...

Answer (score 1):

Just reassign it

```
for x in list:
    x[2] = int(x[2])
```

It's suggested you don't name your variables `list` to conflict with Python internal functions

Answer (score 0):

You may use *list comprehension* to create a new list as:

```
>>> my_list = [['2003', '12', '5'], ['2004', '10', '7']]

>>> new_list = [e[:-1]+[int(e[-1])] for e in my_list]
>>> new_list
[['2003', '12', 5], ['2004', '10', 7]]
```

Comment: looks good.. but it is not dynamic. .. what if the variable is at e[-2]...

['1994', '5', '18', '3', '11668'], ['1994', '5', '19', '4', '11411'], ['1994', '5', '20', '5', '11645'], ['1994', '5', '21', '6', '8830'], ['1994', '5', '22', '7', '8449']

 I am looking to convert third '3' element into int - i.e. ['1994', '5', '18', 3, '11668']

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` in list comprehension:

```
list = [['2003', '12', '5'], ['2004', '10', '7']]
final_list = [[int(a) if i == 2 else a for i, a in enumerate(b)] for b in list]
```

Final Output:

```
[['2003', '12', 5], ['2004', '10', 7]]
```

Edit:

Regarding your new input you posted, you can try this:

```
s = [['1994', '5', '18', '3', '11668'], ['1994', '5', '19', '4', '11411'], ['1994', '5', '20', '5', '11645'], ['1994', '5', '21', '6', '8830'], ['1994', '5', '22', '7', '8449']]
new_s = [[int(a) if i == 3 else a for i, a in enumerate(b)] for b in s]
```

Output:

```
[['1994', '5', '18', 3, '11668'], ['1994', '5', '19', 4, '11411'], ['1994', '5', '20', 5, '11645'], ['1994', '5', '21', 6, '8830'], ['1994', '5', '22', 7, '8449']]
```

Comment: What is the use of "a in enumerate(b)] for b in list]" in your code? I am a naive user..sorry

Comment: @Varun_Sharma `enumerate` allows you to loop through an iterable and store the index of the item and the corresponding value in two variables. In the code above, the list comprehension checks and sees if the index is one less than the length of the list. If that is true, then it castes the value as an integer. If not, it remains a string. Also, `list(enumerate(['2003', '12', '5']))` returns `[(0, '2003'), (1, '12'), (2, '5')]` which is used in the comprehension.

Comment: How can I apply this on the following? 

['1994', '5', '18', '3', '11668'], ['1994', '5', '19', '4', '11411'], ['1994', '5', '20', '5', '11645'], ['1994', '5', '21', '6', '8830'], ['1994', '5', '22', '7', '8449']

I am looking to convert third '3' element into int - i.e. ['1994', '5', '18', 3, '11668']

Comment: How can I apply this on this list: